# "Unknown Class <MyClass> in my Interface builder error" but I don't have a MyClass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Here is the error I am receiving

```
2013-07-30 22:20:53.227 Matchismo[562:c07] Unknown class PlayingCardCollection in    Interface Builder file.
2013-07-30 22:20:53.229 Matchismo[562:c07] -[UIView setSuit:]: unrecognized selector sent   to instance 0x71433f0
2013-07-30 22:20:53.230 Matchismo[562:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setSuit:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71433f0'
```

I don't have a class called "PlayingCardCollection" so I don't see how I could be receiving this error unless I named something wrong but I cannot find an error like that.

Here is some of my code

```
- (Deck *) createDeck
{
return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
}
- (NSUInteger) startingCardCount
{
return 20;
 }
- (void)updateCell:(UICollectionViewCell *) cell usingCard:(Card *) card
{
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[PlayingCardCollectionViewCell class]]) {
    PlayingCardView* playingCardView = ((PlayingCardCollectionViewCell *)cell).playingCardView;
    if ([card isKindOfClass:[PlayingCard class]]) {
        PlayingCard *playingCard = (PlayingCard *)card;
        playingCardView.rank = playingCard.rank;
        playingCardView.suit = playingCard.suit;
        playingCardView.faceUp = playingCard.faceUp;
        playingCardView.alpha = playingCard.isUnplayable ? 0.3 : 1.0;
    }
}
}
```

And this is part of another file.

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
  numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.startingCardCount;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
               cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlayingCard" forIndexPath:indexPath];
Card* card = [self.game cardAtIndex:indexPath.item];
[self updateCell:cell usingCard:card];
return cell;
}
```

If anymore code is needed let me know.  I have alot of files for this project but most weren't touched since my project had its last successful run.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `but I don't have a MyClass` Exactly.  Search your many XIBs for the misspelling you typed into the class field of one of the controls and remove it.

Comment: I kept looking there but I finally found it. Thats exactly what was wrong.  I had too many views inside each other and I guess I didn't check all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why your app is terminating:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setSuit:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71433f0'
```

Looking more carefully at the *reason*, notice that it says:

```
'-[UIView setSuit:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71433f0'
```

The message is telling you that your app tried to send a `setSuit:` message to an instance of `UIView`. The `UIView` class doesn't declare a `setSuit:` method or a `suit` property, so ordinarily this won't work.

The problem may or may not be related to the first issue, where it looks as though you set the identity of an object (possibly a view) in a nib file to a class that you later deleted or renamed. Look at the identities of the objects in the nib file (using the Identity Inspector tab), and see if you can find `PlayingCardCollection`.

If so change it to something more appropriate. Chances are, that's the indirect cause of the runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.The class name set to some view in interface builder as `PlayingCardCollection` and the class does not exist

To find out one best option is to select the nib and right click on it, open it as source code where it shows the xml structure representation of your nib 
Then search for `PlayingCardCollection` and find it.Find the nib with that content and you can find the view from that nib ,More study on the nib itself can sort out the view easily